# Multiline regex not much matching everything

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I got a string with a raw wikipedia data. Part of it looks like this:

```
{{други значения||||Втората балканска война|Междусъюзническа война}}
{{Инфокутия военен конфликт
|име=Балканска война
|резултат=победа за [[Балкански съюз|Балканския съюз]], [[Лондонски мирен договор]], независимост на [[Албания]], [[Междусъюзническа война]]
|страна1=Балкански съюз:<br />• [[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] [[България]]<br />• [[Картинка:Flag_of_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] [[Гърция]]<br />•  [[Картинка:Flag of the Kingdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] [[Черна гора]] <br /> • [[Картинка:State Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] [[Сърбия]]
|страна2= [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Османска империя]]<br/>
|командир1= [[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] [[Фердинанд I]]<br />[[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] [[Михаил Савов]]<br />[[Картинка:Flag_of_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] [[Константинос I]]<br /> [[Картинка:Flag of the Kingdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] [[Никола I]]<br />[[Картинка:State Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] [[Радомир Путник]]
|командир2= [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Назим паша]]<br /> [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Абдулах паша]]<br /> [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Зеки паша]]<br /> [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Али Ръза паша]]
|сила1=
[[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] България - 366 000<br />[[Картинка:State Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] Сърбия - 190 000<br />[[Картинка:Flag_of_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] Гърция - 120 000<br /> [[Картинка:Flag of the Kingdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] Черна гора - 36 000
|сила2=570 000 (максимален брой)
|жертви1=
|жертви2=
}}

More text
```

Notice how the whole content almost is surrounded by {{ and }}.

**The problem:**

The output should look like

```
More Text
```

At this moment it looks like

```
[[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] България - 366 000[[Картинка:State
 Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] Сърбия - 190 000[[Картинка:Flag_of
_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] Гърция - 120 000 [[Картинка:Flag of the Ki
ngdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] Черна гора - 36 000



}}

More Text
```

**The code**

```
 .replace(/^(\*|\||\{).*|\{\{.*?\}\}|<(.|\n)*?>|<!--[\s\S]*?-->/gm, "") // smth
```

Should remove all lines starting with *, |, { or *, remove content in {{ }}, remove tags, remove html comments. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Well, this worked well for me:*

I did a two steps replacement.

Firstly you replace all into `{{` and `}}`:

```
replace(/\{\{[^\{\}]*\}\}/gm, "")
```

Then you replace again the occurrences of (in your words) `lines starting with *, |, { or *, remove tags, remove html` in the rest of the string:

```
replace(/(\*|\||\{).*|\<(.|\n)*?\>|\<\!\-\-[\s\S]*?\-\-\>/gm, "")
```

**The Code**:

```
var html = "{{други значения||||Втората балканска война|Междусъюзническа война}}\n{{Инфокутия военен конфликт\n|име=Балканска война\n|резултат=победа за [[Балкански съюз|Балканския съюз]], [[Лондонски мирен договор]], независимост на [[Албания]], [[Междусъюзническа война]]\n|страна1=Балкански съюз:<br />• [[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] [[България]]<br />• [[Картинка:Flag_of_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] [[Гърция]]<br />•  [[Картинка:Flag of the Kingdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] [[Черна гора]] <br /> • [[Картинка:State Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] [[Сърбия]]\n|страна2= [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Османска империя]]<br/>\n|командир1= [[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] [[Фердинанд I]]<br />[[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] [[Михаил Савов]]<br />[[Картинка:Flag_of_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] [[Константинос I]]<br /> [[Картинка:Flag of the Kingdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] [[Никола I]]<br />[[Картинка:State Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] [[Радомир Путник]]\n|командир2= [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Назим паша]]<br /> [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Абдулах паша]]<br /> [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Зеки паша]]<br /> [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Али Ръза паша]]\n|сила1=\n[[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] България - 366 000<br />[[Картинка:State Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] Сърбия - 190 000<br />[[Картинка:Flag_of_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] Гърция - 120 000<br /> [[Картинка:Flag of the Kingdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] Черна гора - 36 000\n|сила2=570 000 (максимален брой)\n|жертви1=\n|жертви2=\n}}{{други значения||||Втората балканска война|Междусъюзническа война}}\n{{Инфокутия военен конфликт\n|име=Балканска война\n|резултат=победа за [[Балкански съюз|Балканския съюз]], [[Лондонски мирен договор]], независимост на [[Албания]], [[Междусъюзническа война]]\n|страна1=Балкански съюз:<br />• [[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] [[България]]<br />• [[Картинка:Flag_of_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] [[Гърция]]<br />•  [[Картинка:Flag of the Kingdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] [[Черна гора]] <br /> • [[Картинка:State Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] [[Сърбия]]\n|страна2= [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Османска империя]]<br/>\n|командир1= [[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] [[Фердинанд I]]<br />[[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] [[Михаил Савов]]<br />[[Картинка:Flag_of_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] [[Константинос I]]<br /> [[Картинка:Flag of the Kingdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] [[Никола I]]<br />[[Картинка:State Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] [[Радомир Путник]]\n|командир2= [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Назим паша]]<br /> [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Абдулах паша]]<br /> [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Зеки паша]]<br /> [[Картинка:Ottoman Flag.svg|20px]] [[Али Ръза паша]]\n|сила1=\n[[Картинка:Flag of Bulgaria.svg|20px|border]] България - 366 000<br />[[Картинка:State Flag of Serbia (1882-1918).svg|20px|border]] Сърбия - 190 000<br />[[Картинка:Flag_of_Greece_(1822-1978).svg|20px|border]] Гърция - 120 000<br /> [[Картинка:Flag of the Kingdom of Montenegro.svg|20px|border]] Черна гора - 36 000\n|сила2=570 000 (максимален брой)\n|жертви1=\n|жертви2=\n}}\n\nMore text";

var re1 = /\{\{[^\{\}]*\}\}/gm;
var re2 = /(?:\*|\||\{).*|<(.|\n)*?>|<!--[\s\S]*?-->/gm; 

html = html.replace(re1, "").replace(re2, "");
```

**edit:**

Ok, just realized what was wrong with your regex.
You need to put in the order. Firstly you have to replace the content inside the `{{` and `}}`, because there are lines inside its `{{` which wont pass in the other conditions... And consequently will be in the final html.

Then our final expression would be: `\{\{[^\{\}]*\}\}|(?:\*|\||\{).*|\<(.|\n)*?\>|\<\!\-\-[\s\S]*?\-\-\>`

*ps: Dont forget to escape the metacharacters too, like `!` or `-`*

See the [wrong regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/kN0jL7) and the [correct regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/iS5tB3)

Comment: Yeh, that worked out. Weird I tried it before I asked the question and it wasn't working. Thanks.